# Pipe all input and output of terminal to file

Tags: terminal, pipe

I do not know if this is even possible or not, but in an attempt to keep track of many changes I am about to make to my system I want to track all input I type and all output from a terminal I'm working with to a file. I've been messing around trying to do this and here is what I have so far:

`bash > /tmp/output.txt`

This has some quasi success. I tested this with something simple: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` which dumped the normal output to the file, but not what I typed in.

Additionally I'd like to be able to see the output as well as have it stream to my output file, just for readability. (This can be worked around with a second terminal running `tail -f`, but it'd be nice to have it in one place).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Use the Script Command

You probably want the */usr/bin/script* command. It creates a typescript of your current terminal session. It won't work very well with curses-based applications, but works very well for creating a typescript.

For example:

```
script ~/terminal_session.txt
echo foo
echo bar > /dev/stderr
exit
```

will send everything you see on the screen to the named text file.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the "^M" characters that are appended to the end of each line in the `typescript` file produced by a `script` session? Of course, these can be removed easily, but I wonder whether their generation by the `script` command can be avoided in the first place. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For a precise recording of a text session, including timing, without messing up full-screen applications, you can use [ttyrec](http://0xcc.net/ttyrec/).

For interactive applications where text scrolls by, you can use the [`script`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script_(Unix)) command.

Comment: Is there a way to autostart it every time you open a terminal?

Comment: @Qohelet Tell your terminal emulator to run `ttyrec` or `script` instead of your shell. How to do that depends on the terminal emulator.

Comment: @Gilles - thanks, I'm using `xfce4-terminal` and tried already use a script instead of my shell. `ttyrec -a /home/mario/ttyrecs/"$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)"`but I'm just getting there's no file or directory

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `script`:

```
DESCRIPTION
     script makes a typescript of everything printed on your terminal.  It is
     useful for students who need a hardcopy record of an interactive session
     as proof of an assignment, as the typescript file can be printed out
     later with lpr(1).

     If the argument file is given, script saves all dialogue in file.  If no
     file name is given, the typescript is saved in the file typescript.
```

This should be installed by default on most Linux systems since it is part of the `util-linux` package. To use it, just start a your shell like this:

```
script session.log
```

Now, go about your business as usual, it should be completely transparet to you. When you're done, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> or run `exit`. That will save everything you did into `session.log`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do exactly what you're asking for.

However, if you want a record of what you've done the `script` command is probably what you want. It records all typed-in input and all output to a file. It's a text file, usually named "typescript". You will find it in the directory in which you started `script`.

`script` is part of the util-linux package under Arch linux.